# Regex Digit seperated by , or - without number duplication and growing

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex which matches the following example : 1,2-5,7,10...

**Description** : Start with a number, and can optionally be followed by a sequence of "," or "-" with a digit after.

**Restriction** : Can't have a number with more than 4 digits.
Must start and end with a number.
Must not be containing the same number twice or more.
The numbers can't be smaller than the previous numbers (Example : 1,3-7,2 do not match)

In fact I need a range regex.

An example of data which can be entered : 1004,1032,1051,1062,1070,1092,1115,1136,1148,1164,1175,1180,1320,1332,1344,1350,‌​1368,1380,1386,1406,1414,1418,1428,1442,1448,1506,1524,1534,1550,1578,1584,1594,1‌​688,1708,1722,1750,1768,1772,1824,1853,4202-4205,8004,8180

My regex solves some cases, but not the last two:
 (^(\d{1,4}))(([,-]\d{1,4})+)?

Does someone have an idea of how to solve the last two cases ?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: `final String msnPattern = "(^(\\d{1,4}))(([,-]\\d{1,4})+)?";

FieldConditionFactory.createPatternCondition(msnPattern)`

It's really to check just a field write by the user which must match with the regex no more, I try just to know if the fule rule is possible to do in regex.

An example of data which can be entered : 1004,1032,1051,1062,1070,1092,1115,1136,1148,1164,1175,1180,1320,1332,1344,1350,1368,1380,1386,1406,1414,1418,1428,1442,1448,1506,1524,1534,1550,1578,1584,1594,1688,1708,1722,1750,1768,1772,1824,1853,4202-4205,8004,8180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really practical to enforce the last two restrictions with a Regex. As Tobias mentions, Regex is great with patterns but not so much with logic. I would look into other options, for example retrieving the full match in the executing programming/scripting language, splitting on commas, and validating with a loop.

For a slightly more robust regex for what appears to be a list of ranges, try:

```
^\d{1,4}(-\d{1,4})?(,\d{1,4}(-\d{1,4})?)*$
```

This will prevent entries such as 1,2-3-4-5

Comment: Good one, it's a case that i was not plan, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With Regex, you can only check patterns, e.g. only 4 digit numbers, `,` or `-` between them etc., but you cannot check for logic, e.g. be sure that the next number is higher than the previous or make sure no number is used twice (actually, you can, but you would have to write down all numbers possible, in your case 10000 different numbers - I don't think you'd like to do that).

BTW: You could add a `$` at the end to make sure the String ended.

Comment: Yes it's possible to have only one number. Actually my regex work for all case without the two last. So i can have : 
1
1-3
1,2,3
1,2-5,3..
Etc..

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize that `?` is part of your regex, I thought it's part of a sentence. My bad, I'll update. Nevertheless, it would be easier to read if you changed `+` to `*` and removed the `?`, it should do the same